# For loops for discrete values

Tags: linux, bash

Can anyone help me with a for loop? For example, if I wanted values from 1 to 5, 8 to 11, and 13 to 15, I tried this:

```
for value in {1..5;8..11;13..15}
do
echo $value
done
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a sequence of `{N..M}`:

```bsh
for i in {1..5} {11..13} 15; do
    echo $i
done
```

Will result in:

```
1
2
3
4
5
11
12
13
15
```